# Postgres jsonb order rows in the ascending order of a jsonb value

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb field in my table called '*day_parting*'. It looks like this:

```
[{"end_time": 12, "start_time": 0}, {"end_time": 18, "start_time": 17}]
```

It has an array of values, that represent the various start time & end time.

I'm doing a query that joins & filters on two tables and whatever the result I get, I want it ordered in the ascending order of the `day_parting` start times.

Eg:

```
ad1, [{"end_time": 12, "start_time": 11}, {"end_time": 18, "start_time": 17}]
ad2, [{"end_time": 12, "start_time": 7}, {"end_time": 18, "start_time": 13}]
ad3, [{"end_time": 5, "start_time": 4}]
```

On running the query, the ordering should be:

```
ad3, [{"end_time": 5, "start_time": 4}]
ad2, [{"end_time": 12, "start_time": 7}, {"end_time": 18, "start_time": 13}]
ad1, [{"end_time": 12, "start_time": 11}, {"end_time": 18, "start_time": 17}]
```

I have [created a db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f0a635e1c4306a46468ba8fdf640ec81) for my scenario. 
I have been reading postgres jsonb documentation and here is where I've reached:

> select a.*, lateral (select min((dp->>'start_time')::int) x from
>   jsonb_array_elements(a.day_parting) dp) t(x) from merchant_ads a join
>   merchant_devices d on not (d.blacklisted_tags && a.tags) and not
>   (d.blacklisted_brands && array[a.brand::text]),
>   jsonb_array_elements(a.day_parting) where d.device_id = 'device6' and
>   a.active = true and (date(now()) BETWEEN a.start_date AND a.end_date)
>   order by x;

This isnt working and hence my question here, how do I get the ascending ordering such that I order the rows by the start_time of the jsonb values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `ORDER BY` clause like this:

```
ORDER BY (SELECT min(CAST(j->>'start_time' AS integer))
          FROM jsonb_array_elements(day_parting) AS elem(j))
```

Comment: Its ordering correctly but causing certain entries to repeat. Please see the fiddle.

Comment: An `ORDER BY` clause does not influence the number of rows returned. The problem must be in the rest of your query.